Solving Dirichlet Problem

$$
u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta}=0, \qquad 1<r<2
$$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rclccccc}
u(1,\theta) & = & 0, & 0 & \leq & \theta & \leq & 2\pi
\\[2mm]
u(2,\theta) & = & 1+\cos(\theta), & 0 & \leq & \theta & \leq & 2\pi
\end{array}\right.
$$

This satisfies the periodicity condition
$$
u(r,0)=u(r,2\pi)\quad\mbox{and}\quad u_\theta(r,0)=u_\theta(r,2\pi)
$$

Can I apply separation of variables to solve this ?.
I want to write $u(r,\theta) = R(r) S(\theta)$
and sub this into the equation to obtain two separate equations:
$$
S'' + \lambda ^2 S = 0\quad\mbox{and}\quad r^2R''+rR'-R \lambda^2=0
$$
Is this a correct method to start off ?.


@Andrei You are right. Can you please close my question? Thank you.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The general solution of the $2D$-Laplace Equation $\nabla^{2}\on{u}\pars{r,\theta}$ is given by:
\begin{align}
\on{u}\pars{r,\theta} & =
\bracks{A + B\ln\pars{r}}\pars{C\theta + D}
\\[2mm] & +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{A_{n}\sin\pars{n\theta + \phi_{n}}r^{n} +
B_{n}{\sin\pars{n\theta + \delta_{n}} \over r^{n}}}
\end{align}
where $A, B, C, D$ and $\braces{A_{n}, B_{n}, \phi_{n}, \delta_{n} \mid n = 1,2,3,\ldots\rule{0pt}{4mm}}$ are constants. This is what you get after $\ds{\underline{\color{red}{variable\ separation}}}$.

In looking at the boundary conditions, it is clear that the whole problem is invariant under $\ds{\theta \mapsto 2\pi - \theta}$. Therefore, the above general solution becomes
\begin{align}
\on{u}\pars{r,\theta} & =
A + B\ln\pars{r} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{A_{n}r^{n} +
{B_{n} \over r^{n}}}\cos\pars{n\theta} 
\end{align}
where we set $\ds{C = 0,\ D = 1}\ \mbox{and}\ \left.\rule{0pt}{5mm}\phi_{n} = \delta_{n} = \pi/2\right\vert_{\,n\ =\ 1,2,3,\ldots}$.

Lets consider
$\ds{\left.\rule{0pt}{5mm}\on{u}\pars{1,\theta} = 0\,\right\vert_{0\ \leq\ \theta\ \leq\ 2\pi}}\,\,\,\,$:
\begin{align}
0 & = \on{u}\pars{1,\theta} = 
A +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{A_{n} +
B_{n}}\cos\pars{n\theta}
\end{align}
This is satisfien whenever we choose $\ds{A = 0}$ and $\ds{A_{n} + B_{n} = 0,\ \forall\ n = 1,2,3,\ldots}\quad$ The solution is reduced to
\begin{align}
\on{u}\pars{r,\theta} & =
B\ln\pars{r} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_{n}\pars{r^{n} -
r^{-n}}\cos\pars{n\theta} 
\end{align}

In addition,
\begin{align}
\cos\pars{\theta} & = \on{u}\pars{2,\theta} = 
B\ln\pars{2} +\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
A_{n}\pars{2^{n} + 2^{-n}}\cos\pars{n\theta}
\end{align}
which is satisfied with
$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{B} & \ds{=} & \ds{1/\ln\pars{2}}
\\\ds{A_{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{2/3}
\\
\ds{A_{n}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0,\ \forall\ n = 2,3,4,\ldots}
\end{array}\right.$

The final solution becomes
$$
\color{#44f}{\on{u}\pars{r,\theta}} =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{\ln\pars{r} \over \ln\pars{2}} +
{2 \over 3}{r^{2} - 1 \over r}
\cos\pars{\theta},\quad \left\vert\substack{\ds{r \in \bracks{1,2}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\theta \in \bracks{0,2\pi}}}\right.}}
$$
